Build valgrind to target LPC55S69(which is based on Armv8-m architecture)
I'm trying to build valgrind to target baremetal arm cortex-m (based on armv8-m architecture). The host is a x86 wsl environment. How do I specify this while trying to configure valgrind.
For ex: To configure you need to do the following
./configure --target=""
What should be the value for target. I've tried multiple values such as arm-none-eabi, armv8-m etc., with no luck. Is this scenario even possible.
Edit: Host is x86 wsl and that's where I'll be running valgrind

Valgrind doesn't run on baremetal. The ARM platforms that are supported are Linux arm, Linux arm64 and FreeBSD arm64.

@PaulFloyd I would be running valgrind on x86 linux. I just want valgrind to target baremetal cortex-m. Would that be possible?

I don't understand. How can it run on something that is different to the target? Valgrind doesn't perform cross platform binary translation. Some of the README files descibe how to do cross compilation, e.g., ./configure --host=aarch64-unknown-linux.
